# PANIC: Broken AVD system path when starting emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, nativescript

I recently installed Android studio and am having lots of difficulty running an android emulator successfully. I keep getting an error and the console outputs the following message:

```
6:25 PM Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk]!
```

Note, the exported path for `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is actually correct. Has anyone run in to this issue before? I am on Mac and have been trying to get this emulator to run for quite some time.

I have 3 devices installed, Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL and Nexus 5 and made sure to download the images for each, they all generate the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I'm facing same